# Como insertar data de timepicker,textbox y todo el contenido de un datagridview? visual studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

tengo una gran duda acerca de... ¿Cómo hacer que me haga múltiples insert a mi base de datos los registros que están dentro de mi datagridview y tambien fuera de el?.

por ejemplo: Un viaje de tal fecha que seria un dato del datetimepicker, el nombre que tiene el viaje que seria un textbox y insertar todas las personas que irán a ese viaje, en este caso serian todos los que estén en mi datagridview.

```
     Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.conxion)
        Using cm As New SqlCommand()
            cm.Connection = cn
            cn.Open()
            For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In dgv_retiro.Rows
                cm.CommandText = " INSERT INTO retiros (cod_persona, fec_retiro,nom_evento) VALUES (" & dr.Cells("codigo").Value & "," & Retiros.DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString & "," & Retiros.txt_evento.Text & ")"
                cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
            cn.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
```

Lo que ocurre es que me tira el siguiente error

```
Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' en System.Data.dll
```

Información adicional: El nombre de columna 'Pruebanombre' no es válido.

Desde ya muchas gracias!!!.

Comment: Parece ser que estas tratando de insertar un campo en una columna que no existe.

Comment: si eso veo pero entonces mi pregunta es: Como hacer para que me agregue en el insert los datos del datagrid y tambien del datetimepicker con el textbox.

Comment: Y asi como los tienes no estas ingresando el datetimepicker y el textbox?

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo solucione asi:

```
Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.conxion)
            Using cm As New SqlCommand()
                cm.Connection = cn

                cm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO retiros_asistencia  VALUES(@cod_retiro,@cod_persona)"
                cn.Open()


                For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In dgv_retiro.Rows
                    cm.Parameters.Clear()


                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod_retiro", Convert.ToInt32(dr.Cells("cod_retiro").Value))
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod_persona", Convert.ToInt32(dr.Cells("Codigo").Value))
                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next
                cn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
```

Muchas Gracias por ayudarme, de verdad.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas Sergio,

Creo que el problema que hay en esto es que faltan las comillas simples para identificar que es una cadena de texto y que no en la query SQL, en la columna `nom_evento`:

```
cm.CommandText = " INSERT INTO retiros (cod_persona, fec_retiro,nom_evento) VALUES (" & _ 
  dr.Cells("codigo").Value & "," & Retiros.DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString & _
  ",'" & Retiros.txt_evento.Text & "')"
```